# Retrieve first element of a collection via Struts property tag

Tags: java, jsp, collections, struts2

Let's say I have a collections called `imagesNames`.

In my JSP file, I want to display the first element of this collections using Struts property tag.

This is what I have tried, but obviously this won't work.

```jsp
<s:property value='imagesNames[0]' />
```

Comment: What type of collection? *but obviously this won't work* - not so obviously, in general this should work. :)

Comment: Collection of String my friend :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously this won't work, but you can make it working if you populate the collection and provide the public accessors before you return a dispatcher result to the JSP page.

```jsp
<s:property value="imagesNames.first" />
```

Comment: @Bravo: This won't work on **any** collection, only on those which have `getFirst()` method.